# Rename a file in a Document Library - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, script, rename

I am wanting to rename a file name in a document library called `"RenameAFile"`. Currently have the following file called `"UD-PD-Documentattion.xlsx"`

and I want add "DN" before the file name `"UD-PD-Documentattion.xlsx"`.

Output:

```
DN-UD-PD-Documentattion.xlsx
```

Is this possible? Would anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: when you want to change the file, once it uploaded or during the upload process or what?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure it out.

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoursite.com/documentlib"
$DocLib = $Web.Lists["RenameAFile"]          
foreach($ListItem in $DocLib.Items)
   {    
         $ListItem.File.CheckOut()
             $ListItem["Name"] = "DN-"+$ListItem["Name"]
             $ListItem["Title"] = "Add DN"
             $ListItem.Update()
         $ListItem.File.CheckIn("File Name Updated")     
   }
```